# How to get related products shows in the row in Magento?

Tags: php, css, magento

I have problem with costumizing the way that related products shows in Magento product page view.

See the problem here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLx0x.jpg

How to make all products to show in one row, and to show only 4 products?

This is the code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     magento-foundation_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<?php if($this->getItems()->getSize()): ?>

    <div class="block-title">
        <h3><?php echo $this->__('Продукти от същата категория') ?></h3>
    </div>


        <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>

                <?php if(!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                         <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>


                     <ul style="display:inline-block"><li><a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'thumbnail')->resize(100) ?>" width="100" height="100" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" /></a></li> 
                         <li><a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?></a></li>
                       <li> <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-related') ?></li></ul>




                        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>

                        <?php endif; ?>



        <?php endforeach ?>





<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: you need to handle that with a css, are you already using one? @Nasku

Comment: There are many ways but this is a good intro: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listutorial/horizontal_master.htm

Comment: @Unlockedluca i handle to edit the code and this is the result: http://i.imgur.com/NwCMWDM.jpg But now i want to limit number of characters in product name, also to limit number of related products to show.

I edit the post with current code, please see it. Thanks!